# Tensorflow output to terminal is filled with equals sign

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm currently learning Tensorflow using the fashion_mnsit dataset. I created a simple neural network with 3 layers, trained the neural net for 10 epochs and then evaluated to unseen data.

My issue arises when I run the script in the terminal(windows). It displays the progress of each epoch with the "loading bar" represented by:

"[===========>.....] "

But once the training finishes. The terminal screen is completely filled with "================" and then at the very end, the result.

Mine:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbdHf.jpg

Expected:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZwcM.jpg

This is detrimental as I cannot analyze the progression of the model over the epochs.

This is using Tensorflow 2.0 on Python v3.7, 64bit, Windows 10.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and found your question, but no answers. 
I took a guess and added this to my evaluate:

```
results = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels, verbose=0)
```

The verbose = 0 seems to have resolved the issue for me. No more equal signs.